# Changing duration of text in slider

Tags: html, css, timer, slider

A client has a website that has an automatic slider on main page, currently each slide lasts about 3 seconds but want to change this to at least 5 seconds as slides change too quickly and don't give enough time to read text.

This is a purchased template in html so it's already working, would just need to know what to look for or add in css file.

HTML.

```
<section class="hero-fullscreen parallax overlay bg-img-1">  
        <div class="hero-container">  
            <div class="hero-content">   

                <div class="content-slider container">

                    <div class="white">
                        <h5 class="subheading">We set you apart from the competition.</h5>
                        <h1 class="large mt20">Have your own marketing <br> team starting from $$$ a month.</h1>
                        <hr class="separator mb30">   
                        <p class="mb60">We create, manage &amp; update your online presence, so you can focus on your business.</p>
                    </div>
```

CSS.

```
.content-slider.owl-carousel .owl-item,
.content-slider.owl-carousel  .owl-item:active {
cursor: default;
}
 .owl-animated-in {
-webkit-animation-delay: 1s;
-moz-animation-delay: 1s;
-o-animation-delay: 1s;
-ms-animation-delay: 1s;
animation-delay: 1s;
}
.owl-item p, .owl-item h5, .owl-item h1 {
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.animated.bounceIn, .animated.bounceOut, .animated.flipOutX, 
.animated.flipOutY {
animation-duration: 0.6s;
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't look like anything in this css, this is just for the animation in and animation out. It could be defined in JavaScript somewhere. Do you have access to any other files?

Comment: Yes I do. Found this in a "script.js" file and changed 2500 to 7500 and that did the trick. 

    `autoplayTimeout: 2500,   <-------------------------`

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction Jackson.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so looks like there is a script.js file, maybe it wont apply to everyone but Jackson was on the right track.

There's a javascript file with the following section:

```
$(".content-slider").owlCarousel({
    animateOut: 'bounceOut',
    animateIn: 'bounceIn',
    autoplay: true,
    autoplayTimeout: 7500, <--------- Just change this number.
    items: 1,
    dots: false,
    mouseDrag: false,
    touchDrag: false,
    loop: true
});
```